# Using DevicePolicyManager: is it possible to control which APN an application can exit via the mobile network?

Tags: android, mdm, apn

I am working on a network traffic control solution and I would like to know if the Android SDK allows this.

Detailing more about the solution:
Today with my MDM (Mobile Device Management) app, I can add two or more APNs through `DevicePolicyManager.addOverrideApn`.

Now I would like to control which apps can exit these APNs
For example:

APN1

- Whatsapp
- Facebook

APN2

- YouTube
- Gmail
- Hangout

APN3

- All others

The idea is that I can send each group of apps through a different APN so that the phone company can charge properly for each app, making each app have its data package